# Conditions for ratio of convex functions to be convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I would like to know when $\frac{f(x,y,z,w)}{g(x,y,z,w)}$ would be convex. I know that both $f$ and $g$ being convex is not sufficient. Is there any theorem or reference that I can look at?

Comment: I doubt there are general conditions here. As a general rule, the ratio of functions is neither convex nor concave. The exceptions are numerous but then we end up looking at the ratio itself as the "atom". That is, there's really no benefit to considering the resulting function as a ratio anymore.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I see. Thanks for your reply.