# Is $h_{a,b}(C)=\frac{g(C*a)}{g(C*b)}$ concave or convex, or (n)either, For $g$ strictly increasing, convex, and $C>0$, $0<a<b$,?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, ratio

Consider $g$ such that it is

- continuous, strictly increasing, and convex

and two points $0<a<b$

If $h_{a,b}(C)$ is the function that scales these two points two points, applies $g$, and then takes the ratio of these values, i.e.

$$
h_{a,b}(C) = \frac{g(C*a)}{g(C*b)}
$$

can we prove whether $h$ will be convex, concave, or neither? How about whether it is increasing/decreasing?

Or will the result depend on $g$? (looking at [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2715721/conditions-for-ratio-of-convex-functions-to-be-convex), it seems that perhaps it can go either way? But here we have a ratio of a function to itself, just at a different point. Maybe this information allows us to say more)?

---

A comment: I have tried taking the derivative of $h$, i have not been able to get anywhere with it.

---

Another comment: I feel pretty strongly that $h$ should have to be decreasing (and also that it should be convex, but less strongly so about that).

My reason is as follows: Consider two linear functions, with slopes $m_1<m_2$. Then the ratio between any two points $a<b$, with $a$ on the flatter line, is $\frac{m_1 a}{m_2 b}$. If we increasing $m_2$ then this decreasing.

- Wouldn't scaling two points along a convex function be similar to scaling two points along these lines, except that the slopes of the lines are changing as well. However, by convexity, the slope of the "steeper" line is changing faster than the slope of the flatter line.

---

> Edit: Restrict $C$ to be in $(0,\infty)$.

(partly because I forgot to include this, and partly because an answer has been provided for when $C$ can be negative)

Comment: $h$ can be neither convex nor concave. Have you tried some well-known convex functions $g$?

Comment: you cannot simply take the derivative because $g$ might not be differentiable everywhere (think $g(x) = \max\{0.1e^x, x\}$). Should $g$ be nonnegative so the denominator is always nonzero?

Comment: @LinAlg I'm prefer when $g$ is non-negative, but I'm okay with an answer that lets it be negative, as long as the result doesn't hinge on allowing $g$ to be non-negative (or, if it does, then the answer should point it out). About the derivative, I was thinking about differentiable $g$ functions, but you are correct, they need not be. That is an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h$ does not need to be convex, concave, increasing or decreasing. An example is $g(C) = 1 + e^C$, $a=1$ and $b=2$.

[image]

Comment: This is a nice example. Thanks. Although, is it possible for $h$ not be decreasing from $[0,\infty)$? I ask because the increasing section of your example (and I also think the non-convex section...) happens because the denominator becomes evaluated at a smaller number when we are in the negative domain.

Comment: @user106860 for $g(C) = C \log(C)$ (for $C>0.5$), $h$ is increasing

Comment: I'll have to think about that. Thanks